# Windows 7 can't ping .local but other Windows 7 can, on same network

Tags: windows-7, raspberry-pi, mdns

I have two Windows 7 computers, and a standard Raspberian installed Pi3.
The first Windows 7 machine can ping perfectly fine:

```
PING raspberrypi.local
```

The second Windows 7 machine that can ping the IP address of the Pi, but fails with the above command.
All computers are on the same TP-Link router.
All computers are using Wifi.
Both Windows 7 machines have the usual IPv4 and IPv6 settings on auto.

The only difference I can spot is the problem Windows 7 computer is using a cheep RTL8288ETV wifi adapter, the working Windows 7 computer is using a TP-LINK with unknown chip.

As per request here is ipconfig /all for Windows 7 not working:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : AMD-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-33-00-CD-A7-2C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : TP-LINK Wireless USB Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 3C-33-00-CD-A7-2C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::49c0:c30f:fdc6:520b%15(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.105(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 6 September 2016 6:30:55 a.m.
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 6 September 2016 5:30:54 p.m.
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 272380672
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-CC-EE-36-10-C3-7B-4A-07-AA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 10-C3-7B-4A-07-AA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{A718C630-8490-4941-8C46-7044CA147D2F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{C758CB9F-F147-430F-AEF1-03E809E31A8F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Here is Windows 7 working:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Chris-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : 300Mbps Wireless USB Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 64-66-B3-18-5B-61
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::f8fd:35cd:96c1:de10%17(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, 5 September 2016 6:24:56 p.m.
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 6 September 2016 5:24:57 p.m.
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 358901427
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-F2-43-61-48-5B-39-C9-30-AA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 48-5B-39-C9-30-AA
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-14
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::41c9:b542:3c3:9396%20(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 503840807
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-13-F2-43-61-48-5B-39-C9-30-AA
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E25C6FAE-F7C3-42AF-89D4-611342536E54}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{68942613-5683-4D04-B9AA-D50E70BA6A08}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Since you tagged this post with `mdns`, it that machine running the `bonjour` service?

Comment: Use IPCONFIG/ALL and see what differences result.  If you're not seeing it, consider posting the info.  (Scrub it of any confidential details.  IP addresses starting with 192.168 or 10., or 172.16 through 172.31, are typically not needing of scrubbing.)

Comment: @Julie avahi is the standard raspberian mDNS thingie.

Comment: @TOOGAM I added the requested info...

Comment: @TOOGAM:  As mentioned in the second paragraph, below the ping command, the machine can ping it by IP.  The problem is with `mdns` and OP doesn't seem aware that it requires a client service.

Comment: @user975033:  Can you please make sure that machine is running the `bonjour` service?

Comment: @Julie Pelletier Your totally right!, i installed itunes and now it worked. I need to do more research - bit sad that windows needs Bonjour :( If you wish to add it as an answer i'll tick you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mdns` depends on the Apple `bonjour` client service which is part of many Apple packages.

It can also be obtained stand-alone [here](https://support.apple.com/downloads/bonjour_for_windows).

Comment: Yes there was no mDNS responder on the problem windows 7 machine, and it's not built in to windows, news to me :/ Thanks for your help